# jquery toggle with drop effect doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery

I used the drop effect with 3 seconds, but it doesn't work properly.It goes likes show/ hide, with no drop neither 3 seconds.
Any ideas?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#imagem").click(function(ev) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            if ($("div.principal").is(":visible")) {
                $("div.principal").toggle('drop', 3000);
                $("div.tudo").width("675px");
            } else {
                $("div.principal").toggle('drop', 3000);
                $("div.tudo").width("1121px");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead, more control and still easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell, that's not how the stock jQuery toggle() function works. However, jQuery UI does have a 'drop' option and your code works perfectly when the library is referenced:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>TestBed</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/script.js"></script>
        <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="imagem">ImageThing</p>
        <div class="principal">Principal</div>
        <div class="tudo">Tudo</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
'use strict';

$(function() {
    $("#imagem").click(function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        if ($("div.principal").is(":visible")) {
            $("div.principal").toggle('drop', 3000);
            $("div.tudo").width("675px");
        } else {
            $("div.principal").toggle('drop', 3000);
            $("div.tudo").width("1121px");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if toggle takes 2 arguments. If you are trying to delay the toggling by 3 secs, then this might work. It worked for me.

$("div.principal").delay(3000).toggle('drop');